# Smaller Textsize when scaling in Canvas ( Android )

Tags: android, android-canvas, paint, scaling

I draw a text in my custom view with a size of 5. ( I guess 5 means pixels ? ):

```
paint.setTextSize(5);
```

Now I scale the canvas ( Zooming in ) and the textsize is scaled too. 
How can I define the textsize in pixels even the canvas is scaled, so the textsize will be 5 pixels independent of the scale factor ?

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way
paint.setTextSize(convertSizeToDeviceDependent(5));

public int convertSizeToDeviceDependent(int value) {
  DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
  getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
  return ((dm.densityDpi * value) / 160);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this doesn't help. I guess it has nothing to do with Screendensity which I can handle. The Problem is, that the Text will be scaled. Your function convertSizeToDeviceDependent will return a constant depending on the sreensize.